# How to debug when the app is terminated and then launched in xamarin forms using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am developing a Xamarin Forms app using Visual studio.

I want to test this scenario:

1. I open an app
2. Do some operations
3. Terminate the app and launch the application
4. Now I want to hit a break point in Visual Studio

How to achieve this? Mainly I would like to test these events - Suspended, Shutdown and Resume.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: What have you done so far? Just set bp where needed then send app to background then resume. For shutdown your know what to do, right?..

Comment: No possible. You can only catch Start(app start), Sleep(into background) , Resume(back to foreground),  the application will exit debug mode when you shutdown the app.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with [Xamarin. Forms Lifecycle Methods](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/app-lifecycle/):
Put your breakpoints in following methods inside the **App.xaml.cs** class:

> OnStart - Called when the application starts.
>
> OnSleep - Called each time the application goes to the background.
>
> OnResume - Called when the application is resumed, after being sent to
>   the background.
>
> Note that there is no method for application termination. Under normal
>   circumstances (ie. not a crash) application termination will happen
>   from the OnSleep state, without any additional notifications to your
>   code.
>
> To observe when these methods are called, implement a WriteLine call
>   in each (as shown below) and test on each platform.

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    Debug.WriteLine ("OnStart");
}
protected override void OnSleep()
{
    Debug.WriteLine ("OnSleep");
}
protected override void OnResume()
{
    Debug.WriteLine ("OnResume");
}
```